# What is a jersey dress?

Tags: meaning

I came across the term **jersey dress**.  Below are some links to pages that discuss it.  I don't understand what it is.  It sounds like it is a style of dress, but maybe also a dress made from some specific material.  If you could provide a reference to something that gives a definition of some kind, that would be very helpful, thank you.

https://lifestylefifty.com/whats-so-great-about-jersey-dresses/

https://www.newyorkdress.com/blogs/fashion-blog/how-to-style-a-jersey-dress

Comment: Jersey dress: https://www.google.com/search?q=jersay+dress+meaning&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=T8FEZKyqFo3tkgWn25uIAQ&oq=jersay+dress+meaning&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyCQgAEA0QgAQQEzIICAAQHhANEBMyCgghEKABEMMEEAoyCgghEKABEMMEEAoyCAgAEKIEEIsDMggIABCiBBCLAzIICAAQogQQiwM6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6CggAEIoFELADEEM6EgguEIoFENQCEMgDELADEEMYAToPCC4QigUQyAMQsAMQQxgBOgcIABANEIAEOgYIABAeEA06CggAEAUQHhANEBM6CggAEAgQHhANEBM6BQgAEKIESgQIQRgASgUIQBIBMVDYEliKG2CLIGgCcAB4AIABeYgB3QSSAQMyLjSYAQCgAQHIAQ-4AQPAAQHaAQQIARgI&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **jersey dress** is a lady's dress made from [jersey fabric](https://fabriclove.co.uk/blogs/articles/what-is-jersey-fabric-how-can-i-use-it).

As the website under the link above says jersey fabric is

> defined by the way it is constructed, being a knitted, stretch fabric rather than a stable woven material.

There are different types of jersey including **cotton interlock** which is used for T shirts but, in the main, a knitted stretch fabric is a jersey.

Not all stretch fabrics are jersey, however. Lycra is an elastic thread often woven into fabric rather than knitted. It still stretches but because the thread deforms rather than because the knitted construction allows the fabric to deform.

Comment: The jersey knit is stable because it's thick and more complex than a T-shirt.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, the link that BoldBen provided seems to indicate that the material used in a t-shirt is one variety of jersey fabric.  Do you have a source that indicates that the jersey knit is distinct from what is used for t-shirts?

Comment: Before I found the link I thought that _jersey_ was a specific type of stretch fabric (rather loosly knitted, usually from fine wool or a wool-like synthetic) but the article I quoted implies that any knitted (as opposed to woven) stretch fabric is a jersey. As T-shirt fabric is knitted that seems to indicate that it is, technically, a jersey. However I, and I suspect most other people, would not call a dress made out of cotton interlock a "jersey dress".  I don't think that @YosefBaskin and I are very far apart.